# Getting the name info of unknown phone number

Tags: android

Let's say we have got a number.We want to send SMS to this number but in the message body we want the user name.ie. "dear name surname". I searched the internet but could not find any code sample.Is not it possible in android?

Comment: Is that number in your contacts?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that for non-contacts, as the phone doesn't have that information. It's similar to when you get an incoming call: it just displays the number because you don't have more information. It might be possible to find some sort of caller ID service you could use to look up names for numbers, but I don't know if any such thing exists.

Comment: I am working on bulk SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a big problem, is it not ?

Many a times we get calls from phone nos, not in our phone contact list. Those numbers come as unknown numbers. Sometimes the nos, come as masked as well.

So if you are to develop an app to unmask those, how will you get around it ?

Well the solution is you gotta make use of trap calling web sites .

**What are trap calling web sites  ?**

These are web sites , which do a reverse look up of the no that you query and it gives you the name of that number holder.

For e.g, if you are a person in US, then you can make use of the [WhoIsThisPhone](http://whoisthisphone.com/) web site to find out the name of the person calling you.

In case, it's a masked no, you can get around that one too . But you will have to you to pay a subscription fee on a monthly basis for availing this feature(services like trap call are available as apps itself ) .

Depending on which country you are in, you will have to make use of similar services/web sites available to get your job done .

Comment: Do these sites give services for android applications?

Comment: Some of them do, or in some you will have a query box which just takes in the phone no . In this case , while calling the site, you will have to furnish your query like :
`website/q='your phone no'`